# Merging data with irregular time

Tags: r, date, merge, time-series

I am trying to combine dummy variables to a irregular time series *x*.

If the dummy variable occurs on a date that is not present *x*. Then the dummy variable will occur in the next date present in *x*

To illustrate my problem, here is an example :

Let's say that I have dummy variables for an event that happened on 2000-12-15 and 2000-2-18:

```
dummy <-zoo(1,as.Date(c( "2000-12-15", "2000-12-18")))
```

And I have a time series *x*:

```
x <-zoo(rnorm(5),as.Date(c("2000-12-15", "2000-12-16", 
"2000-12-17","2000-12-20", "2000-12-21")))
```

and what I want to have after combining is :

```
                    x dummy
2000-12-15  0.5431835     1
2000-12-16 -1.5612897     0
2000-12-17 -0.1944823     0
2000-12-20  1.2124671     1
2000-12-21 -1.2948487     0
```

For the event on 2000-12-15, the event occurred on a date that is present in *x*. Therefore, there is no issue here. However, for the event that occurred in 2000-12-8, the date is not present in *x*. I want the dummy variable to move to the next date present in *x* which is 2000-12-20. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 1):

```
y <-zoo(1,as.Date(c( "2000-12-15", "2000-12-18")))

x <-zoo(rnorm(5),as.Date(c("2000-12-15", "2000-12-16", 
                       "2000-12-17","2000-12-20", "2000-12-21")))
data<-merge(x,y,all=TRUE)

n<-length(data$x)-1
for(i in 1:n){
  if(is.na(data$x[i]))
   data$y[i+1]<-1
 }

data<-data[complete.cases(data$x),]
data[is.na(data$y),]<-0
```